# Copy New Version of a Database File onto Device

Tags: android

I am having a hard time in DDMS "Push a file onto device" I have an old database file that I like to replace with a new file that I created using sql studio. If anybody have any idea on how to do this please let me know,
thanks
tj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Motodev Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) to rescue! It has files and databases management tools.

Comment: 0  vote down check
 

I am not sure what you mean can you please explain. thanks

Comment: MotoDev Studio has build SQL databases management tools, you can edit you database directly on device (not as powerful as sql studios, but quite usable). It also has a file explorer view (same as in ADT), so you can navigate your files via graphic interface.